# Read a null value in json format in pig

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have a json file with the following format that I'm trying to load in pig:

`{"f1":"DGNJKZH83RRUNTVCQRD1","f2":0,"f3":null}`

I'm using jsonloader() like

```
A = LOAD 'Test.json' USING JsonLoader ('f1:chararray,f2:int,f3:bytearray);
```

Jsonloader works fine for me if f3 field didn't have null and instead had a value but with null value I'm constantly getting an error. Any help on how I can load json files when the value is null will be very helpful.

> ERROR org.apache.pig.pen.AugmentBaseDataVisitor - No (valid) input
>   data found! java.lang.RuntimeException: No (valid) input data found!
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.pen.AugmentBaseDataVisitor.visit(AugmentBaseDataVisitor.java:585)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.accept(LOLoad.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.pen.util.PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.pen.util.PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.walk(PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.java:66)
>     at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)    at
>   org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getExamples(ExampleGenerator.java:180)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.getExamples(PigServer.java:1238)    at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processIllustrate(GruntParser.java:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Illustrate(PigScriptParser.java:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)

Thank you.

Comment: First you should study the documentation for that parser to see how it maps `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been going over the source code  for JsonLoader but not been able to find the answer. Could you please point out what is it that I'm missing: http://search-hadoop.com/c/Pig:src/org/apache/pig/builtin/JsonLoader.java%7C%7C+%2522Map+Reduce%2522

Comment: Can't make heads or tails out of it -- it seems pretty convoluted, and a lot of code is in other files.  But surely there's documentation?

Comment: Digged around a lot , still not been able to find something that can tell me something about the mapping for null.